# Is there a type like Option<'a> that can hold a string in None?

Tags: f#

I need to provide an explanatory message with the None result, so basically I wish I was able to do something like:

```
let func x y z = if x y then Some(z) else None("It didn't work out, because blah blah blah")
```

Is there a standard type for this?

If no, can I use the same Some and None names for a type of my own?

UPDATE:

I gave it a try creating my own union:

```
type CanBe<'a> =
| Some of 'a
| None of string
```

It seems to work, doesn't it?

Comment: Using a custom union like this will work, but it will confuse everyone who will be looking at your code - they will be expecting `Some` and `None` to refer to the standard definitions (and your custom type will not work with the `Option` module). I would recommend using different names - `Success` and `Failure` sound pretty good to me.

Comment: Also, if your failure represents an unexpected failure (as opposed to something that happens for certain valid inputs), then you could consider using exceptions...

Comment: I am validating a value. There are a few different ways that value can be wrong. I need this message for *optional* tracing purposes, which means I don't want to dump into the stdout all the time, but rather leave a option for the calling code to do so if they think it's appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Jon Purdy notes, there is a type you could use for this, but you would be better off with something more specific to what you're doing.  Fortunately it's fairly trivial to implement:

```
type Result<'a> =
  | Success of 'a
  | Failure of string

let func x y z = 
  if x y then Success(z) 
  else Failure("It didn't work out, because blah blah blah")
```

Comment: All good names are already taken I wish I could use Some and None. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: How about success and failure?

Comment: Might be better to define a union type of FailureReasons and then capture one of those in the Failure case, instead of a string

Comment: @CSJ depends on what it is for, `Failure` may or may not actually be an error case.  Maybe `type Result<'a,'b> = | Success of 'a | Failure of 'b`?

Comment: @mydogisbox Good call. Let the user decide :)

Answer (score 5):

The [`Choice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353439.aspx) family of types in `Microsoft.FSharp.Core`:

```
type Choice<'T1,'T2> =
| Choice1Of2 of 'T1
| Choice2Of2 of 'T2
```

Conventionally `Choice2Of2` denotes failure (like `Left` in Haskell) and `Choice1Of2` success—compare Haskell’s `Right`. These names are quite generic, however, and you would do just as well to make your own success/failure type.

Comment: It's the other way around: Choice2Of2 is failure and Choice1Of2 is success.